# Trying to implement Moxtra to my Android application, its giving me an Heap Space error. Any Solutions?

Tags: android, eclipse

While trying to run a sample application of Moxtra, It gives me a Heap Space error.

Did anyone face this earlier too ? Is this fixed ?

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the case, it indicates that you don't have enough memory to run the java based application. Do you run the app on the emulator? If yes, you may try to run it on a real device. And more detail log would be helpful to find an answer.

Comment: No , before it compiles it shows an error of heap space problem.. We are trying to run it on a real device only.

Comment: What's your eclipse configuration? You may try to change its memory config. Or you can try to export your project to gradle or ant build file and build the apk via command. There should be some export options in the eclipse. And try the android studio is a good idea too as it's now the recommended IDE from google.